# Pyspark Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

When I'm working on Pyspark, I get Java Heap Space error when I use any ML algorithm. The data I have is 200 MB, the computer I'm working with is 32GB RAM. I wonder what the problem may be as follows. Can you help me?

The data I have is text-based. I want to do a calculation using this data. There are 200 thousand lines. I can calculate 25 lines, but when I try to calculate more than 25 thousand lines, I get Java Heap Space error.

```
    mySchema = StructType([ StructField("column1", IntegerType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column2", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column3", IntegerType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column4", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column5", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column6", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column7", IntegerType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column8", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column9", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column10", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column11", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column12", IntegerType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column13", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column14", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("column15", StringType(), True)])

data_CSV=pd.read_csv("C:/data.csv", usecols=[7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 18, 28, 29, 35, 36, 58, 81, 82, 83, 84],low_memory=False)

catcols = ['column2','column4','column5','column6']
num_cols = ['column1', 'column3','column7','column12']
labelCol = 'column11'
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_CSV, schema=mySchema)


def get_dummy(df,categoricalCols,continuousCols,labelCol):

    from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
    from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col

    indexers = [ StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(c))
                 for c in categoricalCols ]

    # default setting: dropLast=True
    encoders = [ OneHotEncoder(inputCol=indexer.getOutputCol(),
                 outputCol="{0}_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol()))
                 for indexer in indexers ]

    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[encoder.getOutputCol() for encoder in encoders]
                                + continuousCols, outputCol="features")

    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders + [assembler])

    model=pipeline.fit(df)
    data = model.transform(df)
    data = data.withColumn('label',col(labelCol))

    return data.select('features','label')

data_f = get_dummy(spark_df,catcols,num_cols,labelCol)
data_f.show(5)
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='label',outputCol='indexedLabel').fit(data_f)
labelIndexer.transform(data_f).show(5, True)
featureIndexer =VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures",maxCategories=4).fit(data_f)
featureIndexer.transform(data_f).show(5, True)

(trainingData, testData) = data_f.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed=100)
labelConverter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="predictedLabel",labels=labelIndexer.labels)

print("Logistic Regression")
logr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='indexedFeatures', labelCol='indexedLabel',maxIter=20, regParam=0.3)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer, featureIndexer, logr, labelConverter])
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
predictions = model.transform(testData)
predictions.select("features", "label", "predictedLabel", "probability").show(5)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="indexedLabel", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("True = %g" % (accuracy))
print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the default configuration of your spark session. You need to essentially increase the driver memory by something like this

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").config('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval', '500s') \
        .config('spark.driver.memory', '12g').config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "localhost") \
        .config('spark.executor.memory', '12g').config("spark.network.timeout", "2000s").getOrCreate()
```

What version of Spark are you using? If you are using `SparkContext` and `SQLContext`, you can pass a `SparkConf` object with your configs to the `SparkContext`

You can also edit your `spark-defaults.conf` in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` folder

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the changes you said but gave the same error again. ** Java heap space **